# Can't defining my own properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am working in a `Spring Boot 1.5.9` project and I am trying to configure my class using **externalized configuration**. 
I followed [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) guide and annotated my `@Component` class with `@Configuration`, `@PropertySource` and `@ConfigurationProperties`.

```
@Component 
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-email.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="email")
public class EmailDispatcherService extends Thread {

private String test;

public EmailDispatcherService() {
    System.err.println(test);
    start();
}}
```

At first I tried to set `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` to write in the default file, when this did not work I created my own file folowing this [naming convention](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

I also added the `configuration-processor` to my `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Within the `application.properties` and `application-email.properties`  file I added `email.test=MyTest`. Still, my `test` String is always `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the value for the variable using a `@Value` annotation.

```
@Component 
@Configuration
public class EmailDispatcherService extends Thread {

private String test;

public EmailDispatcherService(@Value("${email.test}") String emailTest) {
    System.out.println(emailTest);
    test = emailTest;
    start();
}}
```